How do I find a english speaking monastery in Bodh Gaya or anywhere in India?
I am from India and can speak Hindi and English. I want to take ordination preferably in Theravada tradition, maybe the Thai traditions. When I do a Google search for monasteries in Bodh Gaya it gives a lot of search results but if I dig deeper they practise in Thai language. I cannot search for English-speaking monasteries as it retrieves the same search results. Is it necessary to know that or Cambodian or Tibetan to join those monasteries?

Please check out the Maha Bodhi Society in Bengaluru. The address of the headquarters is 14, Kalidasa Road, Gandhinagar, Bengaluru-560009, India.
It was founded in 1956 by the late Ven. Acharya Buddharakkhita, who previously studied Buddhism in Sri Lanka and Myanmar. Among his teachers were the famous Venerables Nyanatiloka and Mahasi Sayadaw. You can find his English translation of the Dhammapada here.
Apart from the headquarters in Bengaluru, they also have branches in Mysuru, Hyderabad, Bihar, Arunachal Pradesh and Tripura.
From this YouTube video and this YouTube video, we can infer that English is one of the main languages used at the Maha Bodhi Society in Bengaluru.
From this page:

Mahabodhi Monastic Institute, Bengaluru
Mahabodhi Monastic Institute is a dedicated monastic training center.
It imparts academic and spiritual education to the monks from their
young age. The institute provides education similar to the traditional
education given during the time of the Buddha and later till the
period of Nalanda Buddhist University. The monks are trained in both
study and practice of Buddha’s teaching to grow spiritually and
thereby to become a guiding light to the world. There are 135 pupils
and 16 teacher monks from all over India in the monastery.

And

There are three levels of ordination:

Anagarika Ordination: On admission they are given Anagarika ordination and candidates will remain as Anagarikas for 2-4 years,
depending on their age and learn all the basic things in Vinaya and
Dhamma.
Samanera Ordination: Those who have completed certain level of study and discipline practice get ordained as Samaneras.
Bhikkhu Ordination: On attaining 20 years of age and completing all the basic studies and practice monks get ordained as Bhikkhus.



Thank you for the answer.
